# How do I catch Rayquaza in Pokémon Sapphire?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I'm trying to catch a level 70 Rayquaza. I have a level 55 Kyogre equipped with Quick Claw.

My gameplan is this so far: use Ice Beam to get the Rayquaza to below 10% health, wait for the Rayquaza to use Rest to put itself to sleep, use Ice Beam again to get it to critical health, and finally chuck Ultra Balls at it repeatedly. However, I have tried this for many repetitions without any success.

What improvements can be made to my method to maximize the probability of successful capture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend bringing a Pokemon that can paralyze or put Rayquaza to sleep. Moves like Thunder Wave or Hypnosis come to mind. These will increase your odds. (In addition, Rayquaza awakens from Rest after two turns while putting it to sleep yourself is likely to last longer, and Rest is a headache to contend with anyway.)

Besides that, you're pretty much doing as much as you can, so keep throwing Ultra Balls and hope for the best.

Comment: Ice beam occasionally freezes Rayquaza so I got that going for me I guess :')

Comment: Yeah, but that's only at a 10% chance which isn't really reliable

Answer (score -1):

Well using this Catch Rate Generator is seems like your best bet would be to use a ultra ball. (Ultra Balls give the best chance of catching him). Put the Rayquaza to sleep or to freeze him and then use a Dusk Ball. This will give you about a 4.3% chance to catch him.

Another strategy that could work is using a timer ball. Timer Balls would give a 9.2% chance of catching him after 40 turns. While this gives a high catch chance you would need to use a lot of items keeping your pokemon alive.

https://www.dragonflycave.com/calculators/gen-iii-iv-catch-rate

Comment: There are no Dusk Balls in Emerald.

Comment: It grouped up Sapphire and Diamond. That's my bad. Everything other than the Dusk Ball works really.

Comment: The OP says IN SAPPHIRE, not emerald

Comment: and timer ball is not really viable vs a legendary

Comment: Timer Ball can be helpful for legendary matches that take a while. It's not rare in matches when sleep is involved and after many ball attempts. It's superior to Ultra Balls from turn 21 onwards.

Comment: @TheCosmicTruth Ruby, Sapphire, and Emerald are all the same generations with the same items. The catch rate simulator I was using grouped Diamond and Sapphire together making me think they had the same balls.

Comment: I'd say legendary fights are when Timer Balls are most useful, @TheCosmicTruth. These are battles that tend to take a long time as you try to catch them and fail (unless you are very underlevelled and get wiped out quickly!). Best strategy is to Sleep or Freeze, get to low health, then chuck Ultra Balls until turn 14 and Timer Balls afterwards.

Comment: I'd say timer balls are most useful against a legendary pokemon but the only problem is that legendary pokemon are very powerful and you'd have to use quite a few items keeping your pokemon alive. Of course if you've already reached turn 21 and Ultra Balls are no longer the better ball I'd use timer balls.

Comment: Okay, didn't know that, only done one legendary fight, died almost immediately, so I have no experience.

Comment: Of course master ball is the best...